# I receive 503 Error with .NET 6 Application on IIS 10

Tags: .net, iis, http-status-code-503

I have a problem with a Site deployed on IIS. I searched for solutions and tried many but none of them helped me.

The IIS version is 10 and The OS is Windows Server 2016.
The Application framework is NET 6

The problem is about 503 error that i receive navigating the web site.

If it may helps, the application is connected with 2 DB's on 2 diffrent servers.

- One DB is for application functionality (users, roles, features and
  permissions)
- One DB is for Application Data to be shown (products,    vendors,
  etc...)

If i navigate the part about Users and Roles it's all OK and the application doesn't crash.
If I open a page which refers to the second DB (products, vendors) the api returns the data correctly (the first time) but after that the Application Pool shuts down and I recive the 503 error.

Then I must restart the Application on IIS.

I tried  several solutions:

- Setted Load User Profile to False
- Setted Rapid-Fail protection to false
- Changed application http and https binding ports
- Url rewrite module intalled
- All IIS application features Installed (Web Socket Protocol, CGI, ASP.NET 4.6,3.5...)

I have no errors on the Event Viewer and I can't find any significant error on the IIS logs so I have no trace about error causes.

Thank you,
Federico

EDIT:

After suggestions I used Jexus Manager to make an ASP.Net Core Diagnsotic.
I found that the application hosting model was "inprocess", while I forced the "outofrpocess" in .csproj. So I found that in web.config was setted "inrpocess" as hosting model.
After changing the hostingmodel in "outofprocess" in Web.config , now the App works!

Comment: Run a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html and common issues can be found.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: thank you both for your answer! @LexLi I used Jexus Manager to make a Core Diagnsotic. I found that the appplication hosting model was "inprocess", while I forced the outofrpocess in .csproj. So I found that in web.config was setted "inrpocess". After changing Web config configuration, now the App works! thank you